# Compilation Error while iterating using Linq with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I am building a Linq query that does the following:

- Iterate through each group
- Check if the group contains at least one student with `University= OPQ`
- Make sure that the same group doesn't have any `Student= Adam`.
- Get the first item in each group of students that have `University= OPQ`.

**Output**

- `Emity` (Group 2)
- `White` (Group 5)

**What I tried**

```
    var results = StudentsList
        .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
        .Where(x=>x.Any(y=> y.University=="OPQ") && x.Any(y=> y.Student!="Adam" ))
        .Select(g => 
                {
                    var firstItem = g.Where(x=>x.University=="OPQ");
                    firstItem.IsQualified = true;

                    return firstItem;
                }).ToList();

    foreach(var item in results)
        Console.WriteLine("Group:" + item.GroupID + " Student:" + item.Student +  " IsQualified:" + item.IsQualified);
```

**I get an error:**

> Compilation error (line 56, col 22):
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not
>   contain a definition for 'IsQualified' and no extension method
>   'IsQualified' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**My Code**

```
    List<StudentInfo> StudentsList = new List<StudentInfo>();

    // Group 1
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Gungun", University="cdf", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false});
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="John", University="abc", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false});
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jack", University="def", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Peter", University="abc", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Lemity", University="abc", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );

    // Group 2
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Donald", University="def", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Olivia", University="ggh", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emity", University="OPQ", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emma", University="OPQ", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alan", University="OPQ", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );

    // Group 3
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Adam", University="yub", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jacob", University="OPQ", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Matthew", University="OPQ", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Saint", University="abc", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Joshua", University="qer", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Aubrey", University="fef", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );

    // Group 4
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Caleb", University="DEF", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Anna", University="ABC", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Chill", University="GHI", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alexis", University="JKL", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Zoe", University="MNO", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );

    // Group 5
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Dylan", University="PQR", GroupID = 5, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="White", University="OPQ", GroupID = 5, IsQualified=false} );

public class StudentInfo
{
  public string Student { get; set; }
  public string University { get; set; }
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public bool IsQualified {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3p469)

**Firstly**, You should make sure that the group does not contains any `Student == "Adam"`

**Secondly**, You should make sure that the group contains any least one `University == "OPQ"`

**Finally**, Get the first item of each group with `University == "OPQ"`

```
var results = StudentsList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
                       .Where(g => !g.Any(p => p.Student == "Adam") && g.Any(x => x.University == "OPQ"))
                       .Select(g => 
                                {
                                    var firstItem = g.First(x => x.University == "OPQ");
                                    firstItem.IsQualified = true;

                                    return firstItem;
                                }).ToList();
```

**Your error**

1. `x.Any(y=> y.Student!="Adam" )` should be `!x.Any(y => y.Student =="Adam" )`
2. `var firstItem = g.Where(x=>x.University=="OPQ");` Should be `var firstItem = g.First(x=>x.University=="OPQ")`

Comment: I plan to use multiple conditions inside the `.Select` clause (for example: `firstItem`, `otherItems`, `someOtherItems`). As `return firstItem;` returns only the first item, not `otherItems`, `someOtherItems`, is there a way I can get rid of `return firstItem;` or possibly replace it with a better one?

Comment: Instead of `.Select()`, You can also use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve it.

Comment: You can create a new question, then tag me. I'm willing to help you.

Comment: Thank you. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279851/duplicate-initialization-of-member-error-while-using-linq-query