# Linq list of lists to one list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq

I have a Linq query that updates the first item in each conditioned group like this

```
var results = StudentsList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
    .Where(g => !g.Any(p => p.Student == "Adam") && g.Any(x => x.University == "OPQ"))
    .Select(g => 
            {
                var firstItem = g.First(x => x.University == "OPQ");
                firstItem.IsQualified = true;

                return firstItem;
            }).ToList();
```

While preserving original functionality, I want to additionally-

- If exists, update `IsQualified= true` for ALL students in same group with `University!= "OPQ"` and `Course= "HR"` (Group 2). If don't exist, just ignore (Group 5)

**Output**

- Donald, Silver, Emity (all Group 2) and White (Group 5).

**What I tried**

Just below the `"firstItem.IsQualified = true;"` line, I added-

```
var otherItems=g.Any(x=>x.University != "OPQ" && x.Course =="HR");
otherItems.IsQualified= true;
```

**My Code**

```
    List<StudentInfo> StudentsList = new List<StudentInfo>();

    // Group 1
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Gungun", University="cdf", Course="GD", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false});
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="John", University="abc", Course="ACC", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false});
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jack", University="def", Course="CS", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Peter", University="abc", Course="GD", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Lemity", University="abc", Course="CS", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );

    // Group 2
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Donald", University="def", Course="HR",GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Olivia", University="ggh", Course="RC",GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Silver", University="tcs", Course="HR",GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Carl", University="yyz", Course="AC",GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emity", University="OPQ", Course="AC",GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emma", University="OPQ", Course="GD", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alan", University="OPQ", Course="GD", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );

    // Group 3
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Adam", University="yub", Course="CS", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jacob", University="OPQ", Course="AC",GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Matthew", University="OPQ", Course="HR", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Saint", University="abc", Course="MNGT",  GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Joshua", University="qer", Course="MNGT",  GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Aubrey", University="fef", Course="MNGT",  GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );

    // Group 4
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Caleb", University="DEF", Course="HR", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Anna", University="ABC", Course="HR", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Chill", University="GHI", Course="GD", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alexis", University="JKL", Course="CS", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Zoe", University="MNO", Course="MNGT", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );

    // Group 5
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Dylan", University="PQR", Course="ACC", GroupID = 5, IsQualified=false} );
    StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="White", University="OPQ", Course="CE", GroupID = 5, IsQualified=false} );

public class StudentInfo
{
  public string Student { get; set; }
  public string University { get; set; }
  public string Course { get; set; }
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public bool IsQualified {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: **Course="GD", Course="ACC"** -  (line 13, col 90) Duplicate initialization of member 'Course'  is self-explanatory.

Comment: Sorry for the tag. I have removed it.

Comment: After fixing, I now get Compilation error (line 67, col 18): 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'IsQualified' and no extension method 'IsQualified' accepting a first argument of type 'bool'

Comment: `var otherItems=g.Any(...); otherItems.IsQualified= true;` - variable `otherItems` has `bool` type. there is no IsQualified property in bool

Comment: change ``Any`` by ``Where`` and update ``IsQualified`` in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sVhf0I)

Instead of `.Select()`, You can also use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve it.

```
    var results = StudentsList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
                              .Where(g => !g.Any(p => p.Student == "Adam") && g.Any(x => x.University == "OPQ"))
                              .SelectMany(g => 
                                    {
                                        var firstItem = g.First(x => x.University == "OPQ");
                                        firstItem.IsQualified = true;

                                        var otherItems = g.Where(x => x.University != "OPQ" && x.Course == "HR")
                                                          .Select(z => 
                                                                  {
                                                                      var item = z;
                                                                      item.IsQualified = true;
                                                                      return item;
                                                                  }).ToList();
                                        otherItems.Add(firstItem);
                                        return otherItems;
                                    }).ToList();
```

**Output**

```
Group:2 Student:Donald IsQualified:True
Group:2 Student:Silver IsQualified:True
Group:2 Student:Emity IsQualified:True
Group:5 Student:White IsQualified:True
```

Comment: If we use letter `x` in the line `GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)`, do we have to stick with the same letter in `.Any(x => x.University == "OPQ")` as well? Does using the same letter serves a specific purpose or we can use any letter of our choice?

Comment: **we can use any letter of our choice**

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
        var otherItems = StudentsList.Where(x => x.University != "OPQ" && x.Course == "HR");
        foreach (var otherItem in otherItems)
        {
            otherItem.IsQualified = true;
        }
```

Comment: creating list `ToList()` for sake of using `ForEach()` method is evil. just use `foreach` loop

Comment: @ASh I removed .ToList(), now I get an error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Program.StudentInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument..

Comment: just use `foreach` loop

Comment: @YoKidYo, Let me update the answer as suggested by ASh